# Queuing Actions in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've currently got a situation whereby I need Redux Actions to be run consecutively. I've taken a look at various middlewares, such a redux-promise, which seem to be fine *if you know what the successive actions are at the point of the root (for lack of a better term) action being triggered*.

Essentially, I'd like to maintain a queue of actions that can be added to at any point. Each object has an instance of this queue in its state and dependent actions can be enqueued, processed and dequeued accordingly. I have an implementation, but in doing so I'm accessing state in my action creators, which feels like an anti-pattern.

I'll try and give some context on use case and implementation.

### Use Case

Suppose you want to create some lists and persist them on a server. On list creation, the server responds with an id for that list, which is used in subsequent API end points pertaining to the list:

```
http://my.api.com/v1.0/lists/           // POST returns some id
http://my.api.com/v1.0/lists/<id>/items // API end points include id
```

Imagine that the client wants to perform optimistic updates on these API points, to enhance UX - nobody likes looking at spinners. So when you create a list, your new list instantly appears, with an option at add items:

```
+-------------+----------+
|  List Name  | Actions  |
+-------------+----------+
| My New List | Add Item |
+-------------+----------+
```

Suppose that someone attempts to add an item before the response from the initial create call has made it back. The items API is dependent on the id, so we know we can't call it until we have that data. However, we might want to optimistically show the new item and enqueue a call to the items API so that it triggers once the create call is done.

### A Potential Solution

The method I'm using to get around this currently is by giving each list an action queue - that is, a list of Redux actions that will be triggered in succession.

The reducer functionality for a list creation might look something like this:

```
case ADD_LIST:
  return {
    id: undefined, // To be filled on server response
    name: action.payload.name,
    actionQueue: []
  }
```

Then, in an action creator, we'd enqueue an action instead of directly triggering it:

```
export const createListItem = (name) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(addList(name));  // Optimistic action
        dispatch(enqueueListAction(name, backendCreateListAction(name));
    }
}
```

For brevity, assume the backendCreateListAction function calls a fetch API, which dispatches messages to dequeue from the list on success/failure.

### The Problem

What worries me here is the implementation of the enqueueListAction method. This is where I'm accessing state to govern the advancement of the queue. It looks something like this (ignore this matching on name - this actually uses a clientId in reality, but I'm trying to keep the example simple):

```
const enqueueListAction = (name, asyncAction) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();

        dispatch(enqueue(name, asyncAction));{

        const thisList = state.lists.find((l) => {
            return l.name == name;
        });

        // If there's nothing in the queue then process immediately
        if (thisList.actionQueue.length === 0) {
            asyncAction(dispatch);
        } 
    }
}
```

Here, assume that the enqueue method returns a plain action that inserts an async action into the lists actionQueue.

The whole thing feels a bit against the grain, but I'm not sure if there's another way to go with it. Additionally, since I need to dispatch in my asyncActions, I need to pass the dispatch method down to them.

There is similar code in the method to dequeue from the list, which triggers the next action should one exist:

```
const dequeueListAction = (name) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(dequeue(name));

        const state = getState();
        const thisList = state.lists.find((l) => {
            return l.name === name;
        });

        // Process next action if exists.
        if (thisList.actionQueue.length > 0) {
            thisList.actionQueue[0].asyncAction(dispatch);
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, I can live with this, but I'm concerned that it's an anti-pattern and there might be a more concise, idiomatic way of doing this in Redux.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should take a look to [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga).

Comment: This is a great question, I will be interested to see if anyone has an elegant solution to this. I have been using promise chains + mapDispatchToProps to achieve something similar.

Comment: I think all of us that have done a deep dive into react/redux have found a need to queue/aggregate actions in a way that isn't supported specifically in any of the middleware options. Personally, I think you're better off handling it at the component level, and tracking/comparing state there, instead of in middleware where you'd have to queue/dequeue based on IDs.

Comment: @Pcriulan - Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think redux-saga solves this issue.

From what I can gather from the [documentation](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga), non-concurrent requests for the same action that are picked up by the saga will cancel pending requests.

Admittedly, I've haven't dug too deep into that stuff yet.

Comment: @ajmajmajma - I'm hoping for a more elegant solution too. I still feel like I might be doing something fundamentally wrong or non-idiomatic here. 

I'd be interested in seeing your promise chains approach - does this work if you don't know the full promise chain when triggering the first action? 

That's been the biggest hurdle for me - I need to be able to arbitrarily add and remove from this queue, where actions do not know if there are successive actions.

Comment: @CHBuckingham - That's interesting. I _did_ initially attempt to solve in the components but I was checking state and triggering actions on queues if they existed in the render method (so that whenever there was an update, the queue could be checked and ticked over). This didn't fly - Redux produced an error about the render method remaining pure.

Comment: I would put the "process local queue" logic into one of the lifecycle methods like willReceiveProps.

Comment: Accessing state inside your action creators is not an anti-pattern. Mutating it would be. See this implementation. https://github.com/cerebral/redux-action-tree

Comment: A big issue I would be careful of is trying to access data that does not yet exist, and I definitely would not allow accessing state from async actions.

Comment: So let me make sure I understand. You want to create a queue of all the actions a user is making, that will happen in succession as soon as data from the service shows up? Also to top that off you want it to also handle the async actions too?

Comment: Check out redux-logic http://codewinds.com/blog/2016-08-16-business-logic-redux.html

Answer (score 6):

I have the perfect tool for what you are looking for. When you need a lot of control over redux, (especially anything asynchronous) and you need redux actions to happen sequentially there is no better tool than [Redux Sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/). It is built on top of es6 generators giving you a lot of control since you can, in a sense, pause your code at certain points.

The **action queue** you describe is what is called a **saga**. Now since it is created to work with redux these sagas can be triggered to run by dispatching in your components.

Since Sagas use generators you can also ensure with certainty that your dispatches occur in a specific order and only happen under certain conditions. Here is an example from their documentation and I will walk you through it to illustrate what I mean:

```
function* loginFlow() {
  while (true) {
    const {user, password} = yield take('LOGIN_REQUEST')
    const token = yield call(authorize, user, password)
    if (token) {
      yield call(Api.storeItem, {token})
      yield take('LOGOUT')
      yield call(Api.clearItem, 'token')
    }
  }
}
```

Alright, it looks a little confusing at first but this saga defines the exact order a login sequence needs to happen. The infinite loop is allowed because of the nature of generators. When your code gets to a **yield** it will stop at that line and wait. It will not continue to the next line until you tell it to. So look where it says `yield take('LOGIN_REQUEST')`. The saga will yield or wait at this point until you dispatch 'LOGIN_REQUEST' after which the saga will call the authorize method, and go until the next yield. The next method is an asynchronous `yield call(Api.storeItem, {token})` so it will not go to the next line until that code resolves.

Now, this is where the magic happens. The saga will stop again at `yield take('LOGOUT')` until you dispatch LOGOUT in your application. *This is crucial since if you were to dispatch LOGIN_REQUEST again before LOGOUT, the login process would not be invoked.* Now, if you dispatch LOGOUT it will loop back to the first yield and wait for the application to dispatch LOGIN_REQUEST again.

Redux Sagas are, by far, one of my favorite tools to use with Redux. It gives you so much control over your application and anyone reading your code will thank you since everything now reads one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

The id alone shouldn't go through the reducer. In your action creator (thunk), fetch the list id first, and *then()* perform a second call to add the item to the list. After this, you can dispatch different actions based on whether or not the addition was successful.

You can dispatch multiple actions while doing this, to report when the server interaction has started and finished. This will allow you to show a message or a spinner, in case the operation is heavy and might take a while.

A more in-depth analysis can be found here: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

All credit to Dan Abramov

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem to yours. I needed a queue to guarantee that optimistic actions were committed or eventually committed (in case of network problems) to remote server in same sequential order they were created, or rollback if not possible. I found that with Redux only, fells short for this, basically because I believe it was not designed for this and doing it with promises alone can be really a hard problem to reason with, besides the fact you need to manage your queue state somehow... IMHO.

I think @Pcriulan's suggestion on using redux-saga was a good one. At first sight, redux-saga doesn't provide anything to help you with until you get to [channels](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html). This opens you a door to deal with concurrency in other ways other languages do, CSP specifically (see Go or Clojure's async for example), thanks to JS generators. There are even [questions](https://medium.com/@roman01la/confusion-about-saga-pattern-bbaac56e622) on why is named after the Saga pattern and not CSP haha... anyway.

So here is how a saga could help you with your queue:

```
export default function* watchRequests() {
  while (true) {
    // 1- Create a channel for request actions
    const requestChan = yield actionChannel('ASYNC_ACTION');
    let resetChannel = false;

    while (!resetChannel) {
      // 2- take from the channel
      const action = yield take(requestChan);
      // 3- Note that we're using a blocking call
      resetChannel = yield call(handleRequest, action);
    }
  }
}

function* handleRequest({ asyncAction, payload }) {
  while (true) {
    try {
      // Perform action
      yield call(asyncAction, payload);
      return false;
    } catch(e) {

      if(e instanceof ConflictError) {
        // Could be a rollback or syncing again with server?
        yield put({ type: 'ROLLBACK', payload });
        // Store is out of consistency so
        // don't let waiting actions come through
        return true;
      } else if(e instanceof ConnectionError) {
        // try again
        yield call(delay, 2000);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

So the interesting part here is how the channel acts as a buffer (a queue) which keeps "listening" for incoming actions but won't proceed with future actions until it finish with the current one. You might need to go over their documentation in order to grasp the code better, but I think it's worth it. The resetting channel part might or not work for your needs :thinking:

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would tackle this problem:

Make sure each local list have an unique identifier. I'm not talking about the backend id here. Name is probably not enough to identify a list? An "optimistic" list not yet persisted should be uniquely identifiable, and user may try to create 2 lists with the same name, even if it's an edge case.

On list creation, add a promise of backend id to a cache

```
CreatedListIdPromiseCache[localListId] = createBackendList({...}).then(list => list.id);
```

On item add, try to get the backend id from Redux store. If it does not exist, then try to get it from `CreatedListIdCache`. The returned id must be async because CreatedListIdCache returns a promise.

```
const getListIdPromise = (localListId,state) => {
  // Get id from already created list
  if ( state.lists[localListId] ) {
    return Promise.resolve(state.lists[localListId].id)
  }
  // Get id from pending list creations
  else if ( CreatedListIdPromiseCache[localListId] ) {
    return CreatedListIdPromiseCache[localListId];
  }
  // Unexpected error
  else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("Unable to find backend list id for list with local id = " + localListId));
  }
}
```

Use this method in your `addItem`, so that your addItem will be delayed automatically until the backend id is available

```
// Create item, but do not attempt creation until we are sure to get a backend id
const backendListItemPromise = getListIdPromise(localListId,reduxState).then(backendListId => {
  return createBackendListItem(backendListId, itemData);
})

// Provide user optimistic feedback even if the item is not yet added to the list
dispatch(addListItemOptimistic());
backendListItemPromise.then(
  backendListItem => dispatch(addListItemCommit()),
  error => dispatch(addListItemRollback())
);
```

You may want to clean the CreatedListIdPromiseCache, but it's probably not very important for most apps unless you have very strict memory usage requirements.

---

Another option would be that the backend id is computed on frontend, with something like UUID. Your backend just need to verify the unicity of this id. Thus you would always have a valid backend id for all optimistically created lists, even if backend didn't reply yet.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to deal with queuing actions. It will hide the data flow and it will make your app more tedious to debug.

I suggest you to use some temporary ids when creating a list or an item and then update those ids when you actually receive the real ones from the store.

Something like this maybe ? (don't tested but you get the id) :

**EDIT** : I didn't understand at first that the items need to be automatically saved when the list is saved. I edited the `createList` action creator.

```
/* REDUCERS & ACTIONS */

// this "thunk" action creator is responsible for :
//   - creating the temporary list item in the store with some 
//     generated unique id
//   - dispatching the action to tell the store that a temporary list
//     has been created (optimistic update)
//   - triggering a POST request to save the list in the database
//   - dispatching an action to tell the store the list is correctly
//     saved
//   - triggering a POST request for saving items related to the old
//     list id and triggering the correspondant receiveCreatedItem
//     action
const createList = (name) => {

  const tempList = {
    id: uniqueId(),
    name
  }

  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(tempListCreated(tempList))
    FakeListAPI
      .post(tempList)
      .then(list => {
        dispatch(receiveCreatedList(tempList.id, list))

        // when the list is saved we can now safely
        // save the related items since the API
        // certainly need a real list ID to correctly
        // save an item
        const itemsToSave = getState().items.filter(item => item.listId === tempList.id)
        for (let tempItem of itemsToSave) {
          FakeListItemAPI
            .post(tempItem)
            .then(item => dispatch(receiveCreatedItem(tempItem.id, item)))
        }
      )
  }

}

const tempListCreated = (list) => ({
  type: 'TEMP_LIST_CREATED',
  payload: {
    list
  }
})

const receiveCreatedList = (oldId, list) => ({
  type: 'RECEIVE_CREATED_LIST',
  payload: {
    list
  },
  meta: {
    oldId
  }
})


const createItem = (name, listId) => {

  const tempItem = {
    id: uniqueId(),
    name,
    listId
  }

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(tempItemCreated(tempItem))
  }

}

const tempItemCreated = (item) => ({
  type: 'TEMP_ITEM_CREATED',
  payload: {
    item
  }
})

const receiveCreatedItem = (oldId, item) => ({
  type: 'RECEIVE_CREATED_ITEM',
  payload: {
    item
  },
  meta: {
    oldId
  }
})

/* given this state shape :
state = {
  lists: {
    ids: [ 'list1ID', 'list2ID' ],
    byId: {
      'list1ID': {
        id: 'list1ID',
        name: 'list1'
      },
      'list2ID': {
        id: 'list2ID',
        name: 'list2'
      },
    }
    ...
  },
  items: {
    ids: [ 'item1ID','item2ID' ],
    byId: {
      'item1ID': {
        id: 'item1ID',
        name: 'item1',
        listID: 'list1ID'
      },
      'item2ID': {
        id: 'item2ID',
        name: 'item2',
        listID: 'list2ID'
      }
    }
  }
}
*/

// Here i'm using a immediately invoked function just 
// to isolate ids and byId variable to avoid duplicate
// declaration issue since we need them for both
// lists and items reducers
const lists = (() => {
  const ids = (ids = [], action = {}) => ({
    switch (action.type) {
      // when receiving the temporary list
      // we need to add the temporary id 
      // in the ids list
      case 'TEMP_LIST_CREATED':
        return [...ids, action.payload.list.id]

      // when receiving the real list
      // we need to remove the old temporary id
      // and add the real id instead
      case 'RECEIVE_CREATED_LIST':
        return ids
          .filter(id => id !== action.meta.oldId)
          .concat([action.payload.list.id])
      default:
        return ids
    }
  })

  const byId = (byId = {}, action = {}) => ({
    switch (action.type) {
      // same as above, when the the temp list
      // gets created we store it indexed by
      // its temp id
      case 'TEMP_LIST_CREATED':
        return {
          ...byId,
          [action.payload.list.id]: action.payload.list
        }

      // when we receive the real list we first
      // need to remove the old one before
      // adding the real list
      case 'RECEIVE_CREATED_LIST': {
        const {
          [action.meta.oldId]: oldList,
          ...otherLists
        } = byId
        return {
          ...otherLists,
          [action.payload.list.id]: action.payload.list
        }
      }

    }
  })

  return combineReducers({
    ids,
    byId
  })
})()

const items = (() => {
  const ids = (ids = [], action = {}) => ({
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'TEMP_ITEM_CREATED':
        return [...ids, action.payload.item.id]
      case 'RECEIVE_CREATED_ITEM':
        return ids
          .filter(id => id !== action.meta.oldId)
          .concat([action.payload.item.id])
      default:
        return ids
    }
  })

  const byId = (byId = {}, action = {}) => ({
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'TEMP_ITEM_CREATED':
        return {
          ...byId,
          [action.payload.item.id]: action.payload.item
        }
      case 'RECEIVE_CREATED_ITEM': {
        const {
          [action.meta.oldId]: oldList,
          ...otherItems
        } = byId
        return {
          ...otherItems,
          [action.payload.item.id]: action.payload.item
        }
      }

      // when we receive a real list
      // we need to reappropriate all
      // the items that are referring to
      // the old listId to the new one
      case 'RECEIVE_CREATED_LIST': {
        const oldListId = action.meta.oldId
        const newListId = action.payload.list.id
        const _byId = {}
        for (let id of Object.keys(byId)) {
          let item = byId[id]
          _byId[id] = {
            ...item,
            listId: item.listId === oldListId ? newListId : item.listId
          }
        }
        return _byId
      }

    }
  })

  return combineReducers({
    ids,
    byId
  })
})()

const reducer = combineReducers({
  lists,
  items
})

/* REDUCERS & ACTIONS */
```

Comment: This is something I'm already doing in app. That is, assigning temporary IDs and reconciling them on server response. Admittedly, my shape is a little different.

However, I think this still has the issue of dependent calls. Suppose `FakeItemApi` in your case required the server ID from `FakeListApi` as part of the url string like in the above example. 

Now imagine if someone immediately tried to add a list item before we were guaranteed to have that list id. What would they pass as the second argument to `createList`? A temp ID would surely break the API call.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer, you only need to dispatch the `FakeItemApi` calls in the `createList` action creator. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the amendment, @Pcriulan. I think that solves for this particular case quite elegantly, but possibly not the general case. 

For example, imagine that it's not _just_ adding list items that you might want to do on succession. Perhaps it's a PUT to the list API to change the name or some other arbitrary event. In general, suppose that you want to run events on an API in succession that aren't aware of each other (in your above example, FakeListApi call is aware that FakeListItem call will succeed).

Comment: Van you elaborate more on this ? Why do you mean by "actions that aren't aware of each other" ? They never are, but you do

Comment: Thanks again for the response, @Pcriulan. What I mean is the above action creator for FakeListAPI's async call has a notion of what succeeds it - in its then method, it calls into the FakeListItemAPI. Imagine if we had ten different APIs that all might be interdependent - we'd need to use the same pattern for each API within every action creator that cares (I hope that makes sense). I've went for an approach that couples an async action queue with the notion of optimistic updates but remains highly general and domain-agnostic. I'll try to write a blog post about it in the coming week .