# React/Redux Large Real Time Data List Performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently I have a large list of data (500 Rows) that at times many records can be updated a second. I'm using firebase's Real time Database. I am using React and Redux and basically whenever a record is changed, I fire a dispatch event to update the state in my app. When there are many records being updated it slows down and almost crashes the browser.

I've narrowed down my performance issues to it trying to dispatch 200+ actions at once. But since it is websockets/firebase I have no way of getting these updates in groups.

I am wondering if there is a library to use that will queue the dispatch requests and update the state one at a time, in order. Instead of trying to do it all at once.

Comment: Hi this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742335/queuing-actions-in-redux

Answer (score 1):

Are these issues by any chance occurring in development with Redux dev tools also running?

Redux is fairly optimised to handle large data sets (particularly if you normalise your data structure). However, if you are dispatching a large number of actions and also have a large amount of data in your Redux store, using Redux dev tools can give a somewhat false impression of poor performance.

In a production build of your application there would only ever be one instance of your Redux state at a particular moment. Hence the first of the three Redux principles; single source of truth.

The difference whilst using Redux-dev tools in development however is that the dev tools keep a history of your actions and the state for each action dispatch you trigger. This subsequently can lead to large amounts of that data filling up your browser’s memory and thus giving the perception of poor performance.

You can also take a look at the [Redux documentation on performance](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance) which has several further suggestions for how you can optimise your application.

If you would also like to show us how your data is structured in your reducer, or how you are handling your action dispatches, perhaps we can make further suggestions to improve your performance.